# How to get geolocation from Eircode/Post Code accurately

Tags: google-api

I am trying to get latitude and longitude from Ireland Eircode by using google API but I am not getting data from some  postcodes given below:

A96X7F2
E45XD68

When I am trying to get data from this, It's returning status ZERO_RESULTS
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=A96X7F2&key=API_KEY

Note: In most cases, I am getting data by using this API.

Comment: Your API key is invalid. You need to show the code you are using to make the call for anyone to be able to help you. You should also tag the question with the language you are using. Do not include your actual API key in your question.

Comment: The API key is not invalid because I am getting data from another Eircode. I am requesting from the browser. The API key is hidden for privacy. Please check the screenshot https://snipboard.io/knsoxe.jpg I think It will make you clear. Thank You.

Comment: I thought it was a link to your result; didn't notice it was the url itself. Try specifying the region: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=A96X7F2&region=ie&key=API_KEY

Comment: Yes! It's working well by specifying the region. I have got the solution. Thanks a lot

Comment: No worries. I'll add that as an answer since it solved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try specifying the region:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=A96X7F2&region=ie&key=API_KEY

Issues with postcodes are discussed on their issue tracker here:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73030863?pli=1

They say in that link that for best results use region or component filtering. [Both are ways to specify region, but the former is a hint, the latter is a filter.]